# "Error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message

Tags: python, selenium, exception

I'm encountering an error `NoSuchElementException`.

Here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

login_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='log In']")
login_link.click()

sleep(2)

username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")

username_input.send_keys("<your username>")
password_input.send_keys("<your password>")

login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()

sleep(5)

browser.close()
```

Comment: Some context is missing from your Q. Where does your error occur? What solutions have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and it seems that this step

```
login_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='log In']")
login_link.click()

sleep(2)
```

is unnecessary. Going to `https://www.instagram.com/` sends you straight to the login page on a fresh browser instance.